# React Bootstrap: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use a React Bootstrap Navbar as one of my components. However anytime I copy the code and try to render it it gives me the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of NewSiteNav.

I've tried all I can to troubleshoot it, I've imported/exported the components different ways, updated `react`, `react-bootstrap` and `react-dom` and no success. However when I comment out the navbar code and replace it with normal JSX, it works fine.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './NewSiteNav.css';

class NewSiteNav extends Component {

   
    render() {
       
        return (
                <div>
                    <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
                        <Navbar.Collapse>
                            <Nav defaultActiveKey="">
                                <Nav.Item>
                                    <Nav.Link href="">Active</Nav.Link>
                                </Nav.Item>
                                <Nav.Item>
                                    <Nav.Link eventKey="">Option 2</Nav.Link>
                                </Nav.Item>
                                <Nav.Item>
                                    <Nav.Link eventKey="" disabled>
                                    Disabled
                                    </Nav.Link>
                                </Nav.Item>
                            </Nav>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Navbar>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default NewSiteNav;
```

Comment: Did you import bootstrap in your index file?

Comment: @MonicaAcha Yes :)

Comment: are you sure it is Nav.Item and not NavItem ? bcz the error suggest that you are using something which isn't denfined

Comment: How do I center align the nav items?

Comment: @aravind_reddy I believe the discrepancy between NavItem and Nav.Item is a breaking change in React-Bootstrap 1.0 beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change you imports to

```
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

`NavItem` is not exported as it is `Nav.Item`

Comment: Thank you this helped, although there is still a problem with the Nav.Link. If I remove them it works.

Comment: and while I have you, could you tell me how to center align the nav items in the nav bar?

Answer (score 0):

Answers involving `import` are targeted at NodeJS, but this question is not tagged as NodeJS and I'm getting the same in Flask when my script is inlined in index.html.

I found this helpful:

```
const Tab = ReactBootstrap.Tab;
const Row = ReactBootstrap.Row;
const Col = ReactBootstrap.Col;
const Nav = ReactBootstrap.Nav;
const NavItem = ReactBootstrap.NavItem;

// other code ...

  <Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={1} onSelect={handleSelect}>
    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/home">
      NavItem 1 content
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">
      NavItem 2 content
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={3} disabled>
      NavItem 3 content
    </NavItem>
  </Nav>
```

I also had some issues because I'm dumb and was following documentation for React-Bootstrap 1.0 beta, which requires Bootstrap 4. I'm actually using 0.32.